# How to get scroll direction after using overflow:auto to disable momentum scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I used the overflow property in CSS to disable momentum scrolling on desktop like this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Before this, the scroll event is bound to `window`, and I can use `$(this).scrollTop()` to find out the scroll position, and therefore the scrolling direction.

And now the scroll events is bound to `document.body`, but I couldn't find anywhere I can find out the scroll position. The `scrollTop()` function always return 0, and I couldn't get the direction of scrolling.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the scrollTop() position for the body element:

```
$('body').scrollTop()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/donnellyjoe/8w7g52ka/